# Print Json with object inside object in angularJS using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi guys I have this following JSON external file:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "errors":[

   ],
   "objects":[
      {
         "cod":"8211300",
         "descricao":"Serviços advocatícios"
      },
      {
         "cod":"7111100",
         "descricao":"Serviços de arquitetura"
      },
      {
         "cod":"6204000",
         "descricao":"Consultoria em tecnologia da informação"
      },
      {
         "cod":"6622300",
         "descricao":"Corretores e agentes de seguros, de planos de previdência complementar e de saúde"
      },
      {
         "cod":"8630504",
         "descricao":"Atividade odontológica com recursos para realização de procedimentos cirúrgicos"
      },
      {
         "cod":"7410202",
         "descricao":"Design de interiores"
      },
      {
         "cod":"6202300",
         "descricao":"Desenvolvimento e licenciamento de programas de computador customizáveis"
      },
      {
         "cod":"7112000",
         "descricao":"Serviços de engenharia"
      },
      {
         "cod":"8599699",
         "descricao":"Outras atividades de ensino não especificadas anteriormente"
      },
      {
         "cod":"6391700",
         "descricao":"Agências de notícias"
      },
      {
         "cod":"7311400",
         "descricao":"Agências de publicidade"
      },
      {
         "cod":"8211300",
         "descricao":"Serviços combinados de escritório e apoio administrativo"
      },
      {
         "cod":"9511800 ",
         "descricao":"Reparação e manutenção de computadores e de equipamentos periféricos"
      },
      {
         "cod":"8630503",
         "descricao":"Atividade médica ambulatorial restrita a consultas"
      },
      {
         "cod":"1",
         "descricao":"Outras atividades"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see there's one string inside the object "objects" and I a newbie in angular and facing issues to print this inside my li with ng-repeat.

**Here's my app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('servicos', []);


app.controller('servicos_1', function($scope, $http){

$http.get("https://app-dot-contabilizei-jobs.appspot.com/rest/simulador/atividades").success(function(data){
    $scope.cliente  = data;
    console.log(data);
}); 

});
```

**And here my index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="servicos">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="servicos_1">
    <div>
       <span class="city">City</span><span>Rank</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="table" >
       <li class="city-row" ng-repeat="value in cliente">
          <span class="city-name">{{value.cod}}</span>    
          <span class="city-count">{{value.descricao}}</span>
       </li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

I saw a few questions here but none with object inside object. Can you help me guys?

Another question, there are another 2 externals jsons to request via http.get. I can create another controllers but how can I manage this if my body ng-controller is already with my first controller?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tired $scope.cliente  = data.objects ?

Comment: And for your second question, it is ok to have severall http request in the same controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to point your `$scope.cliente` variable to `data.object` instead of just `data` like this,

```
<ul class="table" >
    <li class="city-row" ng-repeat="value in cliente.object">
       <span class="city-name">{{value.cod}}</span>    
       <span class="city-count">{{value.descricao}}</span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: changed in controller $scope.cliente = data to data.object and the <li> editions and still got nothing on tht output =(

Comment: it worked with     $scope.cliente  = data.objects; and inside the ng-repeat iterating only in cliente. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's in your controller :

```
$scope.cliente  = data.data.objects;
```

Or in your view :

```
<li class="city-row" ng-repeat="value in cliente.data.objects">
```